# Use variable updated in awk bash script

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following command:

```
cat $1 | while read line; do p_k=`echo "$Q*($k/$N)" | bc -l` ; awk -v col="$col_prob" -v pvaluek="$p_k" '{if($col_prob<=pvaluek) print $0}'; k=$((k+1)); done > $out_file &
```

And a input file $1 like that:

```
XXX 405 0 307 98 G 3.9158562774e-33
YYY 401 4 344 61 G 2.28798061371e-15
```

And I want to compare each line the calculated prob pvalue_k with the prob in the file col_prob, and print the line only if it is less.

But the `awk` command does not update the value of `pvaluek`

Comment: What is the value of `col_prob`? The variables in `awk` are not referenced with `$` (drop it for the variable `col_prob`, unless you want to access `$1`, `$2` in file where the values come from that variable)

Comment: awk is not shell and nowhere in your awk code do you attempt to update the awk variable pvaluek so that makes perfect sense. Also see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and post a [mcve] with concise testable sample input and expected output if you'd like help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the entire loop in AWK:

```
awk -v Q="$Q" -v k="$k" -v N="$N" -v col="$col_prob" '{ p_k=Q*k/N; k++ } $col+0<=p_k { print $0 }' $1 > $out_file
```

This solution is shorter and it will work faster than your bash loop.

I don't know what the values of your variables `Q`, `k`, `N`, `col_prob` are but this works:

```
Q=10e-10
k=1
N=10e+10
col_prob=7
awk -v Q="$Q" -v k="$k" -v N="$N" -v col="$col_prob" '{ p_k=Q*k/N; k++ } $col+0<=p_k { print $0 }' YOURFILE
```

Output:

```
XXX 405 0 307 98 G 3.9158562774e-33
```

P.S. Please, choose "best answer" if an answer works for you. I see from your history that you never did this before. You should.

Comment: I had to change a little bit the command, but It worked!
Thansk Andriy!